# Convert terrain vertex position to global position

Tags: unity, terrain, coordinates, linear-algebra

I am trying to set the terrain's heights data at runtime with a simplex noise function, while stumbling with converting the local position of the vertices to global position to use as input to keep the simplex noise continuous.

At this time I am setting up multiple terrains tiles, which I added in the editor.

The `UnityEngine.Terrain` has a size of 1000 units on x and z and a (default) heightmap resolution of 513.

My actual question is; *What am I missing?*

I have the impression that next I should convert the vertex position of one terrain to a world position, so the tiles would be seamless, but the result shows a difference at the borders. The simplex noise function has been tested and is correct.

```cs
private Vector3 toGlobal(Vector3 position, UnityEngine.Terrain terrain)
{

    int     res     = terrain.terrainData.heightmapResolution;
    Vector3 size    = terrain.terrainData.size;

    Vector3 global = new Vector3( position.x / res * size.x, 0, position.z / res * size.z);

    global += terrain.transform.position;

    return global;

}
```

And less interesting, how I use it:

```cs
// Get all terrain tiles and cycle through them
UnityEngine.Terrain[] terrains = Resources.FindObjectsOfTypeAll(typeof(UnityEngine.Terrain)) as UnityEngine.Terrain[];
foreach(UnityEngine.Terrain terrain in terrains)
{

    int         res     = terrain.terrainData.heightmapResolution;
    float[,]    heights = new float[res, res];
    float       height  = 0;

    for (int z = 0; z < res; ++z)
    {

        for (int x = 0; x < res; ++x)
        {

            Vector3 v = toGlobal(new Vector3(x, 0, z), terrain);
            height  = (float)(simplex.Noise(v.x * 0.0001, v.z * 0.0001, 0) + 1) * 0.5);
            heights[x, z] = height;

        }
        
    }

    terrain.terrainData.SetHeights(0, 0, heights);
                
}
```

[image: Gaps between terrain tiles]

Answer (score 1):

It happend to be the way I used the heights array. After my fight with how the `Terrain.terrainData` stores its data, I neglected this aspect.

Within the `foreach`-loop I've assigned the heights to the bidimensional array `float[,] heights' like this:

```
heights[x, z] = height;
```

The `Terrain` uses the rows as first parameter and so it should be:

```
heights[z, x] = height;
```

This solved the main problem. @DMGregory was one step ahead, and solved the next issue already which saved me some time.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a fencepost error.

A terrain with a resolution of 513 has 513 rows, numbered 0 to 512. When you divide by 513 you get a number between 0 and 0.998, instead of reaching all the way to 1. That means your last vertex gets placed slightly less than a full `size` away from the start of the terrain, leaving a narrow gap between this terrain and the next one that's been shifted over by one full `size`.

You need to divide by the number of beams in the fence, not the number of posts:

```
position.x / (res - 1) * size
```

and similarly for z.

Comment: Actually I just found what the problem is. These gabs are the result of not knowing the `float[,] array` has the order of `float[z, x]`. The fun part is that you have answer my next question, which I would have figured myself. But thanks, this speeds it up a bit. Because you are right I upped still.

Comment: But I need some rep first before I can up.

Comment: I can edit to fold both aspects into this answer, or you can post your own answer about the index order aspect.